# AngularJS filter: Smart search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter results in an `ng-repeat`, but with a "smart search" feature, ie. using multiple keywords to search.  The collection is a complex array of objects, containing objects.

According to [Angular Docs: $filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter), you can use `{$: "keyword"}` with the filter function to deepfilter, but I have not gotten it to work.

Snippet:

```
.filter('smartsearch', function () {
    return function (collection, keywords) {
    if (!keywords) {
        return collection;
    } else {
        keywords = keywords.split(" ");
        _.each(keywords, function (word) {
            collection = _.filter(collection, {$: word});
        });
        return collection;
    }
}
```

It seems to return an empty array (`[]`) each time, even though I know I am using a matching keyword

**UPDATE**

Got it working thanks to @gravityplanx pointing me in the right direction, below is the working solution:

```
.filter('smartsearch', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (collection, keywords) {
            if (!keywords) {
                return collection;
            } else {
                keywords = keywords.split(" ");
                $.each(keywords, function (k, v) {
                    collection = $filter('filter')(collection, {$: v});
                });
                return collection;
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using underscores filter method, when you want to be using Angular's.

Simply change `_.filter(` to `$filter(`.

Comment: getting `$filter is not defined` now

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706583/angularjs-filter-is-undefined-when-trying-to-get-filtered-data) is the likely culprit, but diagnosing a `is not defined` error without access to the codebase is an exercise in futility.

Comment: yes, indeed that was the issue, your answer led me to the problem and how to correct it, I will edit my OP and put the working code there.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to have helped.  :)